# iOS app and Facebook "user_photos" permissions

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an application that has to get access to the user's facebook photos and in order to access them I use the following login code to acquire the necessary permission.

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"user_photos"];

// Login PFUser using Facebook
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissionsArray allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState status,NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Logged");
}];
```

The issue here is that my app cannot be granted the "user_photos" permission and from what I have read I understood that I have to submit a review to facebook developers(which takes 7 working days) in order to be granted that permission. To submit a review I need also to provide information such as app description,name,icon,privacy policiy, things that I do not posses right now, since the application is at still at test stage plus a seven days review is a little too much for now, because I want just to test a feature. 
My question is can I somehow bypass this annoying reviews by marking some "test "option in the facebook developer page or by using the ios facebook API or this is not possible. I had no success in finding a solution, if there is one.

Comment: if u get the id of the user

Comment: but how can I get all of the user photos if I have the id? Would that be by using a query and if that is the case, would you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any permission [including user_photos] when developing your app.

When testing your app, just make sure you're logged in as a developer or test user of your app.

Login Review only needs to happen before making the app available people who aren't listed as developers / testers.